# Nintex Forms 2010 External Data Column Validation rule

Tags: sharepoint, nintex-workflow

I'm trying to achieve required validation on Nintex form 2010 External Data Column connected to an external content type. Using regular validation rule like below to check if empty.

```
1. ExternalDataColumn == "" 
2. isNullorEmpty({Self})
```

However, even after I provide a value for the field the required validation is still shows as not satisfied for this type of field and the same works with other field types.  I also tried to implement Custom Javascript in the "Control Settings" but, unfortunately, form settings are not getting saved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you access to data column configuration?

Comment: @Celtik you mean whether i'm able to go for sharepoint configuration or nintex configuration?

Comment: Sharepoint configuration.

Comment: @Celtik i can access data column configuration, but this validation is optional and based on selection it is mandatory

Answer (score 0):

If you go to column settings, you can set it as a required field and Nintex will do this validation automatically. You don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Appreciate your time to reply on this.  However, as i mentioned i cannot set required field validation at the sharepoint field level.  Because, the field should be mandatory only based on the selection of other field on the Nintex form.

Comment: Did you try to add a rule over control field, using inline functions provided by Nintex?

Comment: I tried it and it's not working, that is the issue i explained in my initial post above.  It's issue only with type "External Data Column"